# jquery not reacting to class changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've got this assignment I've got to do, it has to do with a christmas tree where you can click the branches and turn them into ornaments and whatnot.
When the tree is on, you should not be able to change the ornaments.
So far i've got this jquery:

```
$('.branch1, .ornament1, .light1').click(function() 
{
    alert("WARNING - Power off the tree first!");
    die();
});

$('.branch, .ornament, .light').click(function() 
{                             
    this.className = 
    {
       light : 'branch', branch: 'ornament', ornament: 'light'
    }[this.className];
});

$('#treePowerButton').click(function() 
{
    $(".branch, .branch1").toggleClass("branch branch1");
    $(".ornament, .ornament1").toggleClass("ornament ornament1");
    $(".light, .light1").toggleClass("light light1");
    $(".powerStatus, .powerStatus1").toggleClass("powerStatus powerStatus1");
});

$('#treeClearButton').click(function() 
{
    $(".ornament").toggleClass("ornament branch");
    $(".light").toggleClass("light branch");
});
```

But when I turn the tree on and click a branch or ornament it doesn't throw the alert, it just makes the clicked item completely disappear. What am I doing wrong?

here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a1smjgrv/

Comment: BTW, in your fiddle you should wrap all your code in the $(document).ready()

Comment: Changing the classname(s) of an element doesn't change what events are bound to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Refined Answer:

Try this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a1smjgrv/5/. It will accomplish what you're looking for and is much simpler than trying to bind multiple click events on the same element.

---

#### Original Answer:

The problem is that when the page is loaded, there are not any 'branch1', 'ornament1', or 'light1' elements on the page, so the click event containing the alert() is not being bound to anything. There are only 'branch' elements on the page, so the click events for the branches are all that's bound.

When the tree is powered ON and the 'branch' elements are changed to be a 'branch1' class, the click event containing the className update are still attached to that element. So, when it tries to update the class name based on your object literal ({light: 'branch', branch: 'ornament', etc...}), it can't find a match for any of those because the class name of the given element is now 'branch1' instead of 'branch', so it's setting the class name on the element to 'undefined' (hence, the disappearance).

If you want a function to be bound to an element at any point in time that the element is rendered to the page, you'll need to bind it at the document level instead. Something like the following:

```
$(document).on('click', 'branch1', function() {
  alert('SHAZAM!');
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work, could you possibly put it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sure, here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/kx5os2pu/. Sorry for the asinine example, but it was the best I could think of. You'll notice, Bert is on the page when the JS runs, so the click event for Bert works. However, Ernie is not on the page yet, so you'll notice that when you add Ernie, his click event will not work. But with Cookie Monster, when you add him to the page, his click event does work, because it wasn't bound directly to the Cookie Monster element, but rather to the document element, so that the document can respond accordingly whenever a Cookie Monster element is added.

Comment: I tried adding it here: http://jsfiddle.net/a1smjgrv/3/
but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: So what's happening in that situation is the click event bound to 'branch' is firing before the click event bound to the document which acts on 'branch1'. So, by the time the click event on the document is fired, the element has already been changed to have a class of 'undefined' (because of the bug in the 'branch' click event), and therefore there is no 'branch' element to be found through the click event bound to the document.

Comment: Kristofer, I updated my answer with a new jsfiddle. That should accomplish what you need.

Comment: Kristofer, was your question answered?